# POST request from angular to spring rest api

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

I have created a REST API in Spring Bboot and a client application in Angular 4.  I am running both the applications locally. When I test the `POST` method from `postman` it works well, however when I make a `POST` request from the Angular 4 app it results in `400 Bad request`. The REST API displays the following error at  the console as

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing
```

The REST API has a POST method as below:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/newcustomer", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes= "application/json")
    public Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        System.out.println("***********"+customer.getFirstName());
        return customer;
    }
```

The Angular service

```
@Injectable()
export class PostdataService {

  constructor(private _http : Http) {}

  postContactFormData(firstName, lastName, accounts, phoneNumber){
    var body : {firstName , lastName, accounts, phoneNumber};
    var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/newcustomer/', JSON.stringify(body),{
        headers : headers
    }).subscribe(
        () =>{},
        err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

}
```

The `Customer` class

```
public class Customer {

     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String phoneNumber;
     private List<Account> accounts;

     public Customer(){

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your request body through a linter such as jsonlint.com.

The request you are attempting to stringify is not valid json
`{firstName , lastName, accounts, phoneNumber}` should be something like this:

```
{"firstName": "firstName", "lastName": "lastName", "accounts": [1, 2, 3], "phoneNumber": 1.800.123.4567}
```

Comment: Thank a lot Andrew. I got it now. I have created Customer object and then passed it to JSON.stringify(customer); Now json representation is correct.